# group objects based on callback function

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I need to "sort" and put into another object based on the callback function that's given. For example:

```
var list = [{id: "102", name: "Alice"},
            {id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
            {id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}];


groupBy(list, function(i) { return i.name.length; });
```

Should return:

```
  {
    "3": [{id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."}],
    "5": [{id: "102", name: "Alice"},
      {id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}]
```

Here's what I have so far but I'm stuck...

```
function groupBy(arr, cb) {
let result = {};
arr.forEach(function (obj) {
  var group = [];
  group.push(cb(i))
  result[group].push(obj);
}
  return result;
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How i would do that:

```
 function groupBy(arr, cb){
   const res = {};
   for(const el of arr){
     const key = cb(el);
     (res[key] || (res[key] = [])).push(el);
   }
   return res;
 }
```

---

Why it does not work:

```
 function groupBy(arr, cb) {
  let result = {};
  arr.forEach(function (obj) {
    //That creates one group for each obj?
    var group = [];
   //group should contain the obj, not the key?
   group.push(cb(i))
   // Now you are accessing the result by an array as index??
   // And try to push the object to it which will obvipusly fails as you never set result[group] to an array
   result[group].push(obj);
   }
 return result;
//Typo??
)}
```

Comment: thanks, it works! Do you mind telling me what `(res[key] || (res[key] = []))` means when pushing into it? what's the purpose of the `or`?

Comment: @jj008 `if res[key] is truthy (an array), take that, or if not set it to a new array. Then push the object to that`

Comment: Also have a look at `truthy` and `short circuiting` for more info

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `return value` from the `callback` and take a decision on that

```js
var list = [{id: "102", name: "Alice"},
            {id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
            {id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}];

 function groupBy(arr, cb) {
        let result = {};
        arr.forEach(function (obj) {
           var group = [];
           const length = cb(obj)
           // if result[length] is undefined then create a new array with the current object 
           // else push into the existing array
           result[length] ? result[length].push(obj) : result[length] = [obj];   
        })
        return result;

}

console.log(groupBy(list, function(i) { return i.name.length}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array `reduce` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
const list = [{id: "102", name: "Alice"},
            {id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
            {id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}];
            
const result = list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { name } = curr;
  acc[name.length] = (acc[name.length] || []).concat(curr);
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(result);
```